# string parameters in angular/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is going to be dumb, but I can't figure this out, nor find the answer

```
scope.newNote = "";
scope.addNote = function(note) {
    console.log(note);
    if (!note || note === '' || note.trim().length === 0) {
        return;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<wysiwyg textarea-class="form-control" textarea-required ng-model="newNote" enable-bootstrap-title="true"></wysiwyg>

<button class="btn btn-default right" ng-click="addNote(newNote); newNote = null;">Add</button>
```

When I enter a bunch of spaces, this prints "'&''n''b''s''p'';''&''n''b''s''p'';'"

Hence, the note.trim().length is equal to 12

How do I check for strings that are just spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Paste the relevant html here, btw your tag should have ng-click="addNote()" and not on-click

Comment: share your complete controller. shouldn't it be '$scope' instead of 'scope'?

Comment: How do you enter text that it contains `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Updated.  I'm using a textarea to enter text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your question is:**

> How do I check for strings that are just spaces?

**The answer** is that you need is a simple regular expression like this:

```
if (/^\s*$/.test(note)) {
  // stuff
}
```

**Explanation**

`^` -> beginning of string. With this symbol we say: we want to start the matching from the start.

`\s` -> match whitespace characters

`*` -> match 0 or more of the previous characters (In this example it is the \s) . Thanks to the fact that we can match **0** characters the empty string case ( "" ) is covered.

`$` -> end of string. Match the end of string with the expression. Together with the `^` we say: match the whole string, not just a part of it.